# Silverstripe 4 Userform: Upload multiple files in File Upload Field

Tags: silverstripe-4

In SS4, I have a contact form and want to upload multiples files with this form. But now, userform addon doesn't support this purpose (I used File Upload Field). Could you give me any solution for my issue?.
Thank you,

Comment: You could add multiple "File Upload Fields" - I think that userforms field uses `FileField` from framework, which isn't designed to support multiple uploads in a single field. You'd be welcome to raise an RFC on the framework repository to add support for multiple files in it though!